# How to change the style of a normal pane (Not layout pane)

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

well i am new to JavaFx and i haven't been using java for a really long time, so i am having many problems. And the biggest is how to change the bg of the damn pane.

**Below is the Controller class**

```
//Styling prePane
public class Controller {


//Declaring elements
public Pane prePane;
public Button generate;
public TextArea info;
@FXML
ProgressBar progressBar;


public void onGenerate() throws IOException {

    //Styling prePane
    prePane=new Pane();
    prePane.getStyleClass().add("prePane");


    //Creating and embedding progressBar
    generate.setDisable(true);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);


    //Creating task object
    Task copyWorker = createWorker();
    progressBar.progressProperty().unbind();
    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(copyWorker.progressProperty());
    copyWorker.messageProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            System.out.println(newValue);
        }
    });


    //Starting task thread
    new Thread(copyWorker).start();


    //QR Code generation
    String details;
    info.getParagraphs();
    details=String.valueOf(info.getText());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out= net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode.from(details).to(ImageType.GIF).stream();
    File file=new File("D:\\JavaFXQRGenerator-master\\QrGenerator\\QrCode\\details.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(out.toByteArray());
    fos.flush();
}


//Defining the task
public Task createWorker() {
    return new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                updateProgress(i + 1, 10);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

}

**Main Class**

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("QR Generator");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

**Below the actual Style sheet**

```
.prePane{
        -fx-background-image: url("D:\JavaFXQRGenerator-master\QrGenerator\resources\genPane.jpg");
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you created any controls anywhere? If not, try just adding `new Label();` to the code somewhere.

Comment: Can u please explain why?

Comment: CSS isn't applied (by default) until an instance of `Control` (or a subclass) is created. There's a question about this somewhere, but I can't find it with a quick search.

Comment: So where exactly should i put this Label(); that u are suggesting. And what do u mean by control here?

Comment: I was just referring to the [`Control`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) class. And just create it anywhere: the `start()` method will do. But I was really just trying to establish if you had already created any controls, and if that was the problem. It is probably better if you [edit] your question to include a [MCVE] - otherwise we are all just guessing here.

Comment: E.g. another problem might be that your path is probably not correct. See the [documentation for URLs in CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl). Not sure how an absolute windows path is resolved, given it is interpreted relative to the classpath...

Comment: Well the control has been made, so i don't think the problem is there, but let me check the documentation that u have mentioned.

Comment: You are creating a new pane and applying the style to it. I assume you are actually displaying that pane in the UI, and you didn't show us that code for some reason?

Comment: Yes, i am placing a normal pane on top of a container. And I want to style only the pane, not the whole container. And about the code, i only posted that code which i thought was wrong. My reason for not posting the complete code was to just simplify things for you all. I apologize if this has caused you some extra work and time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it contains a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `resources` folder is part of your build path, `genPane.jpg` will be in the root of the classpath. So the correct path, according to the [CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl) is just

```css
.prePane{
        -fx-background-image: url("/genPane.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but I have already tried it and still doesn't work. But still thanks for sticking with my request for this long.